# How to spawn TNT when a gold block is placed?

Tags: minecraft-commands, minecraft-bedrock-edition

I am trying to make like an orbital strike by placing a gold block then about 50-70 block above it about 100 tnt spawns

Comment: Do you need this to be global, or just in a certain coordinate range?

Comment: I wan it to be Global